# How to execute a function at the end of the subprocess Popen process

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Run a series of perl scripts using subprocess and specifically popen, these scripts are run on the windos cmd, these scripts (at the end of each) generate a report file. I need that as soon as the n_script execution process ends I want to execute a function created by me.

```
def callPerlScript(command, path):
  arg = command.split(" ")
  path = path + arg[0]
  arg.pop(0)

  perl_script = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe",path] + arg, stdout=sys.stdout)
  perl_script.communicate()
  #now i want to execute my function after end of process
```

This function will be called n_times inside a for loop by changing the value of the path and maybe some arguments

```
path = "location/where/I/saved/the/various/scripts/"
list = [] #name of each script to execute
for i in list:
 callPerlScript(i, path)
```

Comment: Seems like you would execute the function like you would any other, but calling it. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to be sure that the function that creates me an html page is executed only after all the scripts have been executed, and not that maybe I go to disturb the execution of the callPerlScript function

Comment: communicate() already blocks - it waits the subprocess to finish then resume on the caller routine

Comment: The [`Popen.communciate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/libraryThe/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function blocks and waits for process to terminate.

Comment: ok perfect thanks for the information